# Ajax call is returning object with null values

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an object from view to controller using ajax. but i am getting null values inside the object in controller. My code is as given below.. Could you please help me to solve the issue

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
function Save() {
    // var Trip={output};
    debugger;
    var stop;
    var table = $('#scheduletable').DataTable();
    var rows = $('#scheduletable tr');
    var StopNames = '';
    var TripNumbers = '';
    var TripDetails = '';
    StopNames += table.column(0).data().toArray().join("&");
    for (var i = 1; i < rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        TripNumbers += rows[0].cells[i].innerText + '&';
        TripDetails += table.column(i).data().toArray().join("&");
    }
    debugger;
    TripNumbers = TripNumbers.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
    var output = {
        'StopNames': StopNames,
        'TripNumbers': TripNumbers,
        'TripDetails': TripDetails
    };
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ScheduleManagement/ScheduleManagement/SaveSchedules",
        // contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(output),
        success: function (values) {
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

I am using the below code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveSchedules(TripsToSave output)
{
    // dynamic item = output;
    int serviceId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ServiceGroupId"]);
    // int status= _scheduleManagementBL.SaveMasterSchedule(output);
    return Json("1", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    // return RedirectToAction("DisplayHttpError", "Error");
}
```

Entity I am using in this code is

```
public class TripsToSave
{
    public string StopNames { get; set; }
    public string TripNumbers { get; set; }
    public string TripDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the way you pass data in ajax request you get params by directly StopNames, TripNumbers, TripDetails not via output.

Comment: Just `data: output,` (or if you do stringify it, then you need `contentType: 'application/json;'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try this

```
 var output = {
        StopNames: 'StopNames',  // change the value with string
        TripNumbers: 'TripNumbers', // change the value with string
        TripDetails: 'TripDetails' // change the value with string
    };

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ScheduleManagement/ScheduleManagement/SaveSchedules",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(output),
    success: function (values) {
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

dataType: 'json',

> Its mean return type of data from server should be json

contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

> Its mean data type should be json before to send it to server in your case you need to convert your data into json stringfy..

Note:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead More detial please visit - Visit

Comment: Thanks for your help.. it is working fine when i changed my code as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to stringify the output data, pass is as it is.

```
        var StopNames = 'ss';
        var TripNumbers = 'ss';
        var TripDetails = 'cc';

           var output = {
            'StopNames': StopNames,
            'TripNumbers': TripNumbers,
            'TripDetails': TripDetails
        };

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/abc/SaveSchedules",

            dataType: "json",
            data: output,
            success: function (values) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```